# DES encryption in Rubymotion

Tags: ios, objective-c, encryption, rubymotion, des

How can I encrypt/decrypt a string with DES algorithm on iOS using Rubymotion?

There are very few examples even on Obj-C, and they are hardly translatable to Rubymotion.

Comment: Backend server which I should send encrypted data already uses DES. The problem is I can't find any good example that uses CommonCrypto with DED neither in Rubymotion or Obj-C

Comment: If you really require the insecure single DES, you can use DES EDE where all the keys are set to the same value.

Comment: Updating: It seems now that the server is using 3DES, not that bad but not suggested for new work. 3DES encryption is usually specified EDE because that is the encryption sequence, the decryption sequence would be DED. Apple Common Crypto supports 3DES EDE (which would be DED for decryption).

Comment: Note, there are some odd-ball implementations that are DED for 3DES encryption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to install CommonCrypto pod.

After I used this code to encrypt with DES:

```
string = "string to encrypt"
data = params.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

errorPtr = nil # You can use a real error object here if you need
encrypted_data      = data.DESEncryptedDataUsingKey(User.first.key, error: errorPtr)
```

Also you can check other aviable encryption and decryption methods in  `/vendors/Pods/CommonCrypto/NSData+CommonCrypto.m` file.